# How to specify Databricks Cluster Policy Family from Terraform?

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

When I create a Databricks Cluster Policy from the UI, I can choose a Policy Family.
This Policy Family let's us have a base template JSON, which we can then override by passing custom JSON tags of our own. It works fine.

When I create a similar policy from Terraform using databricks_cluster_policy resource type, I have to pass the full JSON with all the tags.
***How can I choose a Policy Family from Terraform script***, so that I dont have to pass a large JSON and I can only pass the few JSON tags that I need to customize the policy with?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you tried?Are you trying to create azure databricks cluster policy

Answer (score 1):

Cluster Policy Families aren't supported yet in the Databricks Terraform provider (most probably after migration to Go SDK is finished). Currently the workaround could be to pull definition from another cluster policy using the `databricks_cluster_policy` data source ([doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/data-sources/cluster_policy)) and merge your customizations into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported with the version 1.25.1 of databricks terraform provider:   [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/cluster_policy).

You can now pass on a `policy_family_id` and `policy_family_defintion_overrides`.

**Update 05-10-2023:**
Based on one of the answers, about the difficulty of finding the policy family id- it is indeed not very straightforward, but instead of hardcoding it anywhere, this is how someone can do it , basically,

1. define a config for your cluster policy (I did it in yaml)- this includes the name of the base policy on  which it is based,
2. Use the data block of terraform to query the the existing cluster policies.
3. building a map of policy_family_name (the friendly name that you get in Databricks UI for the list of predefined cluster policies) and the policy_family_id.
4. then do a lookup on that when creating your cluster policy.

Something like this:

**config in yaml**

```
Policy:
  name: "Personalized_Personal_Compute_Policy"
  policy_family_name: "Personal Compute"
  policy_family_definition_overrides:
    dbus_per_hour:
      type: "range"
      maxValue: 4
    autotermination_minutes:
      type: "range"
      minValue: 10
      maxValue: 60
  AclPermissions:
    - principal: Aad-GroupName
      privilege: "CAN_USE"
```

**Parsing the config:**

```
locals {
  cluster_policy_files = fileset("config/${var.environment}/cluster_policies/", "**")
  cluster_policy_files_details = [for f in local.cluster_policy_files :
    {
      filecontent = yamldecode(file("config/${var.environment}/cluster_policies/${f}"))
    }
  ]
  cluster_policy = flatten([
    for policy in local.cluster_policy_files_details :
    [policy.filecontent.Policy
    ]
    ]
  )
}
```

**Finally creating the cluster policy**

```
data "databricks_cluster_policy" "existing_base_policies" {
  for_each = { for policy_iter in local.cluster_policy : policy_iter.name => policy_iter }
  name     = each.value.policy_family_name
}

locals {
  base_policy_with_family_id = {
    for policy in data.databricks_cluster_policy.existing_base_policies : policy.name => policy.policy_family_id
  }
}

resource "databricks_cluster_policy" "policies" {
  for_each                           = { for policy_iter in local.cluster_policy : policy_iter.name => policy_iter }
  name                               = each.key
  policy_family_id                   = lookup(local.base_policy_with_family_id, each.value.policy_family_name)
  policy_family_definition_overrides = jsonencode(each.value.policy_family_definition_overrides)
}

....code to apply permissions- not putting here as that is not the scope of this question.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that will help everyone looking for it - a list of the policy family ids - something I really would've like to have found online, and not in the guts of the API.

```
"policy_families"

"name": "Personal Compute"
"policy_family_id": "personal-vm"

"name": "Shared Compute"
"policy_family_id": "shared-compute"

"name": "Power User Compute",
"policy_family_id": "power-user"

"name": "Job Compute"
"policy_family_id": "job-cluster"

"name": "Legacy Shared Compute"
"policy_family_id": "shared-data-science"
```

Comment: It was indeed more work, for me too. I have now updated the answer to put more details on how to derive it, and not make a static list.